# Pivot table field headers unable to turn into row headers

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I consider myself to be proficient in excel, VBA, and pivot tables. I can not figure out how to move the column header in a pivot table E.G. "P.O." from the column header into the row header. It is driving me nuts!!!!

For example.
[image]

I need "P.O." to be placed to the left of the P.O. number while the pivot table is in compact form. The "P.O." portion is discoverable only when I hover the mouse over the number when in compact form.

[image]

I have work arounds to make this work. I can use a number of formulas and get what I want, but I was hoping I could simply change a Pivot table option and acquire my desired format.

I saw a question like this without an answer. If it isn't possible to change the pivot table options, I will make a formula to do what i want. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You could add another column called 'Transaction Type' and input 'PO' for every row and add it to the PivotTable... but you will never get it on the same line using 'Compact'.  Why must it be 'Compact'?

Comment: Hi Cruter, Its for a print format. I think I may just use a formula out to the side which will look up the column header in the original data! Thanks